# how to solve error when using make with caffe

Tags: ubuntu, makefile, ubuntu-16.04, caffe

I am trying to install caffe on my ubuntu 16.04 machine, and I encountered this error.
I have already done some research on how to solve this kind of problem, but I think this error is quite rare that I could not find any solution to this specific question.

```
k@k:~/caffe$ make all -j4
PROTOC src/caffe/proto/caffe.proto
NVCC src/caffe/solvers/sgd_solver.cu
NVCC src/caffe/solvers/adadelta_solver.cu
NVCC src/caffe/solvers/adagrad_solver.cu
NVCC src/caffe/solvers/adam_solver.cu
NVCC src/caffe/solvers/nesterov_solver.cu
NVCC src/caffe/solvers/rmsprop_solver.cu
NVCC src/caffe/util/im2col.cu
NVCC src/caffe/util/math_functions.cu
NVCC src/caffe/layers/accuracy_layer.cu
NVCC src/caffe/layers/mvn_layer.cu
NVCC src/caffe/layers/sigmoid_cross_entropy_loss_layer.cu
NVCC src/caffe/layers/hdf5_output_layer.cu
NVCC src/caffe/layers/cudnn_lcn_layer.cu
NVCC src/caffe/layers/scale_layer.cu
NVCC src/caffe/layers/dropout_layer.cu
NVCC src/caffe/layers/recurrent_layer.cu
NVCC src/caffe/layers/exp_layer.cu
NVCC src/caffe/layers/filter_layer.cu
NVCC src/caffe/layers/cudnn_lrn_layer.cu
NVCC src/caffe/layers/deconv_layer.cu
NVCC src/caffe/layers/swish_layer.cu
NVCC src/caffe/layers/cudnn_relu_layer.cu
NVCC src/caffe/layers/embed_layer.cu
NVCC src/caffe/layers/tile_layer.cu
NVCC src/caffe/layers/log_layer.cu
NVCC src/caffe/layers/split_layer.cu
NVCC src/caffe/layers/cudnn_conv_layer.cu
NVCC src/caffe/layers/slice_layer.cu
NVCC src/caffe/layers/cudnn_sigmoid_layer.cu
NVCC src/caffe/layers/bias_layer.cu
NVCC src/caffe/layers/batch_reindex_layer.cu
NVCC src/caffe/layers/eltwise_layer.cu
NVCC src/caffe/layers/softmax_layer.cu
NVCC src/caffe/layers/cudnn_pooling_layer.cu
NVCC src/caffe/layers/softmax_loss_layer.cu
NVCC src/caffe/layers/cudnn_softmax_layer.cu
NVCC src/caffe/layers/euclidean_loss_layer.cu                                                                                        
NVCC src/caffe/layers/hdf5_data_layer.cu                                                                                             
NVCC src/caffe/layers/elu_layer.cu                                                                                                   
NVCC src/caffe/layers/contrastive_loss_layer.cu                                                                                      
NVCC src/caffe/layers/prelu_layer.cu                                                                                                 
NVCC src/caffe/layers/concat_layer.cu                                                                                                
NVCC src/caffe/layers/threshold_layer.cu                                                                                             
NVCC src/caffe/layers/pooling_layer.cu                                                                                               
NVCC src/caffe/layers/bnll_layer.cu                                                                                                  
NVCC src/caffe/layers/power_layer.cu                                                                                                 
NVCC src/caffe/layers/im2col_layer.cu                                                                                                
NVCC src/caffe/layers/sigmoid_layer.cu                                                                                               
NVCC src/caffe/layers/batch_norm_layer.cu                                                                                            
NVCC src/caffe/layers/silence_layer.cu                                                                                               
NVCC src/caffe/layers/tanh_layer.cu                                                                                                  
NVCC src/caffe/layers/cudnn_tanh_layer.cu                                                                                            
NVCC src/caffe/layers/relu_layer.cu                                                                                                  
NVCC src/caffe/layers/clip_layer.cu                                                                                                  
NVCC src/caffe/layers/absval_layer.cu                                                                                                
NVCC src/caffe/layers/lrn_layer.cu                                                                                                   
NVCC src/caffe/layers/lstm_unit_layer.cu                                                                                             
NVCC src/caffe/layers/base_data_layer.cu                                                                                             
NVCC src/caffe/layers/inner_product_layer.cu                                                                                         
NVCC src/caffe/layers/conv_layer.cu                                                                                                  
NVCC src/caffe/layers/cudnn_deconv_layer.cu                                                                                          
NVCC src/caffe/layers/crop_layer.cu                                                                                                  
NVCC src/caffe/layers/reduction_layer.cu                                                                                             
CXX tools/upgrade_net_proto_text.cpp                                                                                                 
CXX tools/compute_image_mean.cpp                                                                                                     
CXX tools/extract_features.cpp                                                                                                       
CXX tools/upgrade_solver_proto_text.cpp                                                                                              
CXX tools/convert_imageset.cpp                                                                                                       
CXX tools/caffe.cpp                                                                                                                  
CXX tools/upgrade_net_proto_binary.cpp                                                                                               
CXX examples/mnist/convert_mnist_data.cpp                                                                                            
CXX examples/siamese/convert_mnist_siamese_data.cpp                                                                                  
CXX examples/cifar10/convert_cifar_data.cpp                                                                                          
CXX examples/cpp_classification/classification.cpp                                                                                   
CXX .build_release/src/caffe/proto/caffe.pb.cc                                                                                       
CXX src/caffe/data_transformer.cpp
CXX src/caffe/common.cpp
CXX src/caffe/internal_thread.cpp
CXX src/caffe/solvers/adagrad_solver.cpp
CXX src/caffe/solvers/adam_solver.cpp
CXX src/caffe/solvers/nesterov_solver.cpp
CXX src/caffe/solvers/sgd_solver.cpp
CXX src/caffe/solvers/rmsprop_solver.cpp
CXX src/caffe/solvers/adadelta_solver.cpp
CXX src/caffe/parallel.cpp
CXX src/caffe/syncedmem.cpp
CXX src/caffe/util/math_functions.cpp
CXX src/caffe/util/db_leveldb.cpp
CXX src/caffe/util/insert_splits.cpp
CXX src/caffe/util/upgrade_proto.cpp
CXX src/caffe/util/blocking_queue.cpp
CXX src/caffe/util/io.cpp
CXX src/caffe/util/cudnn.cpp
CXX src/caffe/util/db.cpp
CXX src/caffe/util/im2col.cpp
CXX src/caffe/util/benchmark.cpp
CXX src/caffe/util/db_lmdb.cpp
CXX src/caffe/util/signal_handler.cpp
CXX src/caffe/util/hdf5.cpp
CXX src/caffe/layer_factory.cpp
CXX src/caffe/net.cpp
CXX src/caffe/layers/loss_layer.cpp
CXX src/caffe/layers/slice_layer.cpp
CXX src/caffe/layers/euclidean_loss_layer.cpp
CXX src/caffe/layers/log_layer.cpp
CXX src/caffe/layers/data_layer.cpp
CXX src/caffe/layers/softmax_layer.cpp
CXX src/caffe/layers/hdf5_output_layer.cpp
CXX src/caffe/layers/cudnn_lrn_layer.cpp
CXX src/caffe/layers/lstm_layer.cpp
CXX src/caffe/layers/accuracy_layer.cpp
CXX src/caffe/layers/cudnn_softmax_layer.cpp
CXX src/caffe/layers/relu_layer.cpp
CXX src/caffe/layers/silence_layer.cpp
CXX src/caffe/layers/inner_product_layer.cpp
CXX src/caffe/layers/embed_layer.cpp
CXX src/caffe/layers/cudnn_conv_layer.cpp
CXX src/caffe/layers/neuron_layer.cpp
CXX src/caffe/layers/cudnn_deconv_layer.cpp
CXX src/caffe/layers/concat_layer.cpp
CXX src/caffe/layers/prelu_layer.cpp
CXX src/caffe/layers/cudnn_sigmoid_layer.cpp
CXX src/caffe/layers/cudnn_pooling_layer.cpp
CXX src/caffe/layers/tanh_layer.cpp
CXX src/caffe/layers/cudnn_lcn_layer.cpp
CXX src/caffe/layers/scale_layer.cpp
CXX src/caffe/layers/tile_layer.cpp
CXX src/caffe/layers/hinge_loss_layer.cpp
CXX src/caffe/layers/deconv_layer.cpp
CXX src/caffe/layers/infogain_loss_layer.cpp
CXX src/caffe/layers/image_data_layer.cpp
CXX src/caffe/layers/threshold_layer.cpp
CXX src/caffe/layers/recurrent_layer.cpp
CXX src/caffe/layers/lstm_unit_layer.cpp
CXX src/caffe/layers/pooling_layer.cpp
CXX src/caffe/layers/sigmoid_layer.cpp
CXX src/caffe/layers/cudnn_tanh_layer.cpp
CXX src/caffe/layers/im2col_layer.cpp
CXX src/caffe/layers/spp_layer.cpp
CXX src/caffe/layers/parameter_layer.cpp
CXX src/caffe/layers/batch_reindex_layer.cpp
CXX src/caffe/layers/conv_layer.cpp
CXX src/caffe/layers/sigmoid_cross_entropy_loss_layer.cpp
CXX src/caffe/layers/base_data_layer.cpp
CXX src/caffe/layers/power_layer.cpp
CXX src/caffe/layers/argmax_layer.cpp
CXX src/caffe/layers/bnll_layer.cpp
CXX src/caffe/layers/dropout_layer.cpp
CXX src/caffe/layers/reshape_layer.cpp
CXX src/caffe/layers/mvn_layer.cpp
CXX src/caffe/layers/memory_data_layer.cpp
CXX src/caffe/layers/swish_layer.cpp
CXX src/caffe/layers/lrn_layer.cpp
CXX src/caffe/layers/split_layer.cpp
CXX src/caffe/layers/clip_layer.cpp
CXX src/caffe/layers/multinomial_logistic_loss_layer.cpp
CXX src/caffe/layers/hdf5_data_layer.cpp
CXX src/caffe/layers/filter_layer.cpp
CXX src/caffe/layers/batch_norm_layer.cpp
CXX src/caffe/layers/exp_layer.cpp
CXX src/caffe/layers/bias_layer.cpp
CXX src/caffe/layers/contrastive_loss_layer.cpp
CXX src/caffe/layers/cudnn_relu_layer.cpp
CXX src/caffe/layers/input_layer.cpp
CXX src/caffe/layers/absval_layer.cpp
CXX src/caffe/layers/rnn_layer.cpp
CXX src/caffe/layers/reduction_layer.cpp
CXX src/caffe/layers/window_data_layer.cpp
CXX src/caffe/layers/softmax_loss_layer.cpp
CXX src/caffe/layers/dummy_data_layer.cpp
CXX src/caffe/layers/eltwise_layer.cpp
CXX src/caffe/layers/elu_layer.cpp
CXX src/caffe/layers/crop_layer.cpp
CXX src/caffe/layers/base_conv_layer.cpp
CXX src/caffe/layers/flatten_layer.cpp
CXX src/caffe/layer.cpp
CXX src/caffe/blob.cpp
CXX src/caffe/solver.cpp
AR -o .build_release/lib/libcaffe.a
LD -o .build_release/lib/libcaffe.so.1.0.0
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -latlas,
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find /usr/local/lib: File format not recognized
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
Makefile:581: recipe for target '.build_release/lib/libcaffe.so.1.0.0' failed
make: *** [.build_release/lib/libcaffe.so.1.0.0] Error 1
```

I am new to this field of linux system and commands like make. If further information is needed, please just let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried installing libatlas-base-dev ?